# sticky is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So, here is a thing.

I am loading several scripts via functions.php file in WP, like so:

```
wp_register_script('load-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.min.js', array(), '2.2.4'); // jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('load-jquery'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.7'); // Bootstrap
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('sticky', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.sticky.js', array(), '1.0.4'); // Sticky
wp_enqueue_script('sticky'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!
```

My scripts file looks like this:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

        'use strict';

            // sidebar width as parent 
            $('.sidebar').width($('.sidebar').parent().width());


            // sticky
            $(".page-menu").sticky({topSpacing:0});

    });

})(jQuery, this);
```

First code snippet (that calculates width) works properly but on second i am getting "not a function" error.

jquery is loaded properly (so is the sticky.js) and i cant figure out why it isnt working...

i know there are tons of questions like this, but i am going crazy...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that you need to include the registered script handle that the loading script depends on. Sticky depends on jQuery.

> **$deps**
>    *(array) (Optional)* An array of registered script handles this script depends on.
>   *Default value: array()*
>   -https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
wp_register_script('sticky', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.sticky.js', 
    array(), '1.0.4'); // Sticky
```

should be

```
wp_register_script('sticky', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.sticky.js', 
    array('jquery'), '1.0.4'); // Sticky
```

Comment: Yup. He doesn't have to wp_enqueue_script('sticky), just register it and make his args script use that as a dependency it will load before: `wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery', 'sticky'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts` -- also, if a plugin uses that handle 'sticky' you will have issues if it's not the same script, so I make handles that are iffy with a theme prefix.